# MSBuild doesn't find async required references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asynchronous, msbuild

We have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Async CTP (SP1 refresh) installed.

A solution with projects that use `async/await` keywords builds OK when build from VS IDE.
Also when built with `devenv /build "Debug" solution.sln` everything is OK.

However `msbuild @commands.rsp solution.sln` reports:

```
File.xaml.cs(123): error CS1993: Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?
```

commands.rsp looks like this:

```
/nologo
/p:Configuration=Debug
/m:3
/fileLogger
```

Any clues?

Comment: Can you post your commands.rsp?

Answer (score 4):

Please, refer to the discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk-UA/async/thread/3d491cb0-a19f-4faf-80a6-5fd05e4e06db

There are 2 points to be clarified in order to understand better your problem:

- Environment: did you install VS11 side-by-side with VS 2010+Async CTP?
- Your project: do you have XAML with user controls and "clr-namespace" in your project?

I will cite the preliminary conclusion by *SERware* from the discussion on the MS forum:

> I think it has to do with the order in which the XAML projects
>   compile assemblies when referring to classes of the library itself. In
>   this case, the XAML Loader try to compile this classes before having
>   reference to the Async CTP library. So, the keyword "async" is not
>   recognized.

Personally I am going to see whether it is possible to split the assembly in order to resolve the order of the compilation of the dependencies in XAML

Added after further investigation:
As I have found out, the explanation is even more disappointing: the .NET 4.5 (Beta) replaces the .NET 4.0. Besides, the signatures of the async/wait related types have been internally changed. Therefore there is no way so far to use simultaneously VS 2010+AsyncATP and VS11 Beta. – Yuri S. 2 mins ago

Comment: First point, Yes I do have VS11 installed. However my workmate doesn't, and he got same errors. On the second point, all async/await calls in our case are in ViewModel, so they don't have a counterpart xaml (my error example there is misleading because I didn't have ours in scrollback anyways and that was the one that had same error description and code)

Comment: As I have found out, the explanation is more disappointing even more:
the .NET 4.5 (Beta) replaces the .NET 4.0
Besides, the signatures of the async/wait related types have been internally changed. Therefore there is no way so far to use simultaneously VS 2010+AsyncATP and VS2011 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by this myself and for various reasons I can't upgrade the projects to .NET 4.5 so I had to develop a workaround.

Since this is only a problem for XAML projects that has a `xmlns` declaration pointing to itself I'm able to use async on all the other projects that are referenced. This means my architecture is still utilizing async/await and is prepared for the move to .NET 4.5 later.

But in the affected XAML projects, I just manually implement (poorly) the await things otherwise done by the compiler.

**So code that was this clean before:**

```
try
{    
    var foo = GetFoo();
    foo.DoStuff();
    var data = await foo.GetDataAsync();
    bar.WorkOnData(data);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Logging, throw up a popup, whatever...
    HandleError("Failed to get data", ex);
}
```

**Now becomes this:**

```
var foo = GetFoo();
foo.DoStuff();
var getDataTask = foo.GetDataAsync();
getDataTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Logging, throw up a popup, whatever...
            HandleError("Failed to get data", t.Exception);
            return;
        }
        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            bar.WorkOnData(t.Result);
        }
     });
```

Not ideal of course, and this is the exact thing that `async/await` was created to solve. But it does work as a short-term workaround at least for simple uses of `await`.